# Ninject создает сервис при каждом запросе контроллера?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, dependency-injection, ninject

Использую такую регистрацию сервиса в .NET ASP:

```
kernel.Bind<IService>().To<Service>();
```

после получаю сервис в контроллере.

Я знаю что в .NET ASP Core можно при регистрации сервиса использовать разные 
 методы стандартного IOC-контейнера (AddScoped, AddSingleton, AddTransient) и это повлияет на то как сервис будет получен в контроллере.

Данный метод Ninject создает каждый раз новый сервис (как AddTransient)?
Если это можно настроить было бы интересно узнать как.

Comment: Если вы читали про [жизненный цикл зависимостей](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/6.2.php), то наверное видели и простой [пример](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/2.20.php) задания разным способом зависимостей. Всё просто: создаём некоторый сервис, возвращающий случайные числа и по-разному его инстанцируем. Вам могут дать и готовый ответ -- но вы можете разобраться гораздо глубже, если попробуете сами создать пример и попробовать. Это даст самый главный навык в программировании: умение самостоятельно получать знания, а не копипастить с so. Попробуйте, это не сильно сложно.

Comment: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Answer (score 1):

Как правило, популярные библиотеки хорошо задокументированы.

`Ninject` как раз из них и как следствие первым делом нужно обращаться к [документации](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki), потом погуглить и если вопросы все еще остались, то задать вопрос.

Это было небольшое лирическое отступление, а теперь к делу.

Если обратится к конкретному разделу [документации](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes), то там описаны настройки поведения:

- `Transient`- создается каждый раз
- `Singleton`- создается один раз
- `Thread`- создается на каждый поток
- `Request`- создается на каждый запрос
- `Named`, `Call`, `Parent`- гибкая настройка поведения
- `Custom`- кастомное поведение